# How to restart current seconds to 59 and start counting down

Tags: python, time

I'm trying to make a break timer. I can get the current second value, but I don't know how to reset the seconds and start counting down

I've tried several formulas found here on stack overflow, but have yet to find what I'm looking for

```
import time

while True:
    now = time.localtime(time.time())
    print(now[5])

    time.sleep(1)
```

I expect the output to count down from 59 and start over
output: count up from current second

Comment: Have you tried [`threading.timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects)?

Comment: Please update your question with the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use something like:

```
import time
sec = 0

while True:
   print(59 - sec)
   time.sleep(1)
   sec = (sec + 1) % 60
```

Comment: this was exactly what i was looking thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Here is version with a defined function. It will countdown at defined seconds, taking `sleep` every seconds.

```
import time

    def countdown(t_sec):
        while t_sec:
            mins, secs = divmod(t_sec, 60)
            timeformat = '{:02d}'.format(secs)
            print(timeformat)
            time.sleep(1)
            t_sec -= 1 

    countdown(59)
```